# Flutter webview is blank on IOS but working on android

Tags: ios, flutter, webview

I'm using flutter webview to present the payment url in my app using the following class:

```
class YourWebView extends StatelessWidget {
  String url;
  bool isFinshed = false;
  YourWebView(this.url);


  final Completer<WebViewController> _controller =
      Completer<WebViewController>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('اكمال عملية الدفع..'),
          leading: new IconButton(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.close),
              onPressed: () {
              
              if(isFinshed) {
                      Provider.of<MatchProvider>(context, listen: false)
                              .getMyComingMatches();
                        Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
              } else {
                
                Navigator.pop(context);
              }
               
              }),
        ),
        body: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return WebView(
            initialUrl: Uri.encodeFull(url),
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
            onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
              _controller.complete(webViewController);
         
            },
            debuggingEnabled: true,
            onPageFinished: (String url) {
              SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.hide');
              
              if (url.contains("tap/check?tap_id")) {
                    
                     isFinshed = true;
              }
              print('Page finished loading: $url');
            },
            gestureRecognizers: null,
          //  gestureNavigationEnabled: false
          );
        }));
  }
```

The url looks like:
https://xxxxxx.com/tap/check?tap_id=chg_TS05162021120xxxxxxx

Everything is working on Android, but on IOS i get a blank screen and i see this error in xcode debug logs :

```
WebPageProxy::didFailProvisionalLoadForFrame
```

I have tried to run another urls on the webview and it was working, but the payment url isn't, even though it's working on Android or other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you maybe tried to load a http link in webview instead of https. In that case you should add the following in your info.plist file.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>  
<dict> 
   <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>  
</dict>
```

Comment: The link is https, and I already tried this solution and it did not work..

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Flutter, but on iOS, if the system's process for rendering the web content terminated, the webview would be blank, the flutter plugin is handling the situation in [here](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/b0bfab678f83bebd49e9f9d0a83fe9b40774e853/packages/webview_flutter/webview_flutter_wkwebview/ios/Classes/FLTWKNavigationDelegate.m#L120), you may have to check the error and do a reload.